# Resourses won't display in network monitor (firefox)

Tags: web, firefox, browser

So in html i specify a path to an image (for example:

```
<img src="img_galaxy.jpg">
```

Unlike chrome, when i inspect element i this don't see this image nor other resource  displayed in network monitor section.

i have a small gif to demonstrate about what i mean. Sorry for loss of quality, i had to optimize.

[Left: Firefox | Right:Chromium]

[image]

Sample code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <title>Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <img
            sizes="(max-width: 1400px) 100vw, 1400px"
            srcset="
                   img/jeremy-thomas-E0AHdsENmDg-unsplash_bbrljk/jeremy-thomas-E0AHdsENmDg-unsplash_bbrljk_c_scale,w_320.jpg 320w,
                   img/jeremy-thomas-E0AHdsENmDg-unsplash_bbrljk/jeremy-thomas-E0AHdsENmDg-unsplash_bbrljk_c_scale,w_914.jpg 914w,
                   img/jeremy-thomas-E0AHdsENmDg-unsplash_bbrljk/jeremy-thomas-E0AHdsENmDg-unsplash_bbrljk_c_scale,w_1321.jpg 1321w,
                   img/jeremy-thomas-E0AHdsENmDg-unsplash_bbrljk/jeremy-thomas-E0AHdsENmDg-unsplash_bbrljk_c_scale,w_1400.jpg 1400w"
            src="img/jeremy-thomas-E0AHdsENmDg-unsplash_bbrljk/jeremy-thomas-E0AHdsENmDg-unsplash_bbrljk_c_scale,w_1400.jpg"
            alt="">
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: would you kindly provide the full HTML of your sample? The minimum amount of code required to reproduce your issue.

Comment: of course, my friend. full source code here: https://pastebin.com/1bDkgddj

Comment: I embedded the source code within your question, for better readability! A few notes: are the CSS files required to reproduce the problem?

Comment: CSS files doesn't effect the problem, so no.